# QLabel load image from file

Tags: c++, qt5, qimage, qlabel

I use Qt Resource System to load images.

But Resource Collection Files (.qrc) only 20MB

So I try to use QImage::loadFromData to load image for my application to use.

But for Resource Collection Files (.qrc) I use

```
QImage image0(":/images/dashboard_n.png");
```

to load image .

How to load image with `QImage::loadFromData`

How to use relative path for qrc?

And I can't compile and update the terminal.qrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually it's common to put your image.png file in the directory that your *.qrc is located for example like this:

```
${Project_Resource_Directory}/images/dashboard_n.png
```

and the .qrc file would be placed here:

```
${Project_Resource_Directory}/resources.qrc
```

your .qrc file should look like this:

```
<RCC>
     <qresource prefix="/">
         <file>images/dashboard_n.png</file>
     </qresource>
</RCC>
```

put this code in your .pro file:

```
RESOURCES += ${Project_Resource_Directory}/resources.qrc
```

replace your resources directory name in your project structure instead of ${Project_Resource_Directory} so Qt can detect your *.qrc file and compile them to c code using rcc

then you can just use this address in any of your cpp codes using this:

```
":/images/dashboard_n.png"
```

Comment: Thank for answering but  Project_Resource_Directory I can set desk like RESOURCES += ${C:/Users/user/Desktop/qrc}/terminal.qrc     How to compile with rcc .

Comment: no you have to replace it the whole ${...} it's like : 'RESOURCES += C:/Users/user/Desktop/qrc/terminal.qrc' the absolute or relative path to the .qrc file then the qt will detect resources and will automatically compile it with rcc, usually you don't have to do that manually

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example to load to a QPixmap using loadFromData.. you can load to a qimage the same way but you will have to convert it to pixmap anyway to load it to a qlabel

```
 QByteArray *temp = new QByteArray();
 QFile *file = new QFile("image.png");
 file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
 *temp = file->readAll();
 QPixmap *pix = new QPixmap();
 pix->loadFromData(*temp);
 label->setPixmap(*pix);
```

Comment: Can I where put the image.png? for Resource Collection Files (.qrc) it put inside qt file.

Comment: yes or inside some folder this is how you add it like this : http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/resources.html